# Update query that update existing data in that column

Tags: mysql, tree

I have MySQL table and there is two column 'Id' and 'Pid' (like ID: 125232521,125232522,125232525). I want to replace them like (ID: 1,2,3) and important is that there is ID and Pid are not unique.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please elaborate the question.
1.) On what basis, you would like to replace ?
2.) what data does 'Pid' column contains, how is it significant wrt 'ID' column.

Comment: it is tree structure table. 'ID' and 'PId' are of interger type, these id will assign to some one ti will not assign to another.

Comment: if it is possible to generate tree by these id please help in that, i write these query but it not written full tree it skip some node that depth is more in tree

Comment: my query is :   select ID,PId
  from(select * from test_tree
         order by PId, ID) base,
        (select '@'pv := 100000) tmp
where   find_in_set(PId, '@'pv) > 0
and     '@'pv := concat('@'pv, ',', ID)